# deployment autocad .net dll

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

An Autocad programmer knows that the result of a programme is a `DLL` file that should be registered in windows registry according to which Autocad version installed

any one knows how to make installer to deploy the `DLL` to another machine 
and how can we know which Autocad version is installed and where the installation directory by c#?

Comment: I would strongly doubt that you are legally allowed to do this.

Comment: If there were something illegal in there, I'll be in prison for several years ;-)

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille Why would it be illegal? Adding an entry to the registry is one of the supported/documented methods of having a plugin load automatically.

Comment: I didn't read the original question right.  I thought he wanted to redistribute an autocad dll as opposed to his own.  Illegal was also a bit of a stretch.. more like against licensing terms.  Redistribution of dlls is covered by licensing terms and Autodesk is known for being very protective of Autocad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Building an Installer](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2010/09/building-an-installer-part-1.html)

the link above will solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

All these informations are stored in the registry. For example, for AutoCAD 2010 French :

1. Directory where acad.exe can be found: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.0\ACAD-8001:40C\AcadLocation
2. Commercial product name : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.0\ACAD-8001:40C\ProductName

R18.0 -> AutoCAD 2010, R18.1 -> AutoCAD 2011...

8001 -> AutoCAD 2010, 8007 -> AutoCAD Electrical 2010...

40C -> French...

And if I can give you an advice, don't build your installer with Visual Studio.

Comment: thank you if i will not use visual studio which tool can i use to make good installer

Comment: I would also be interested in your experiences with installers. I install my Acad plugin with the VS Setup and a user dll. Are they any better ways to do this?

Comment: @Maxence - hi max thank you for your answer. i just forward the released build DLL to the relevant people who need it without using an installer: am i doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of simple matters, the Visual Studio Setup is good and enough, or even a bit overkilled. Using a .REG file may sound easier.

If you'd like to detect what AutoCAD versions are available on each machine and give users a chance to choose against which the add-in will be registered, the Custom Action comes to rescue.

Comment: Please stop posting the "Signature" on your posts with your blog URL and tagline, or your posts and account risk being deleted as spam. I am going to edit it out of your existing answers for you, but I trust you will no longer post it in new answers you make.

Comment: @spiderinnet1 thanks spider - a question: i'm about to deploy my autocad plugin. it references another dll. I create a set up project in Visual Studio. Then I have to select a template. If I am using the community edition of Visual Studio then i can't select any templates. Am I doing this right?